# This application is currently offline

Tags: asp.net

I was working(learning) with Data bound controls in ASP.Net and suddenly got the error:

**This application is currently offline. To enable the application, remove the app_offline.htm file from the application root directory.**

I started searching it on google but ended up with no helpful solution. I was not able find app_offline.htm file also. And then I suddenly tried to open my project in browser again and it opened successfully and now its working. And now I have observed that in between as I am working on the project it shows this error in between (cant say when and on what criteria) and then after some time it starts working again. Can anybody help me why its happening?

I am using ASP.Net4.0 and Sql Server Express Edition.

**EDIT**

With somemore searching on google it seems that this gets created automatically in the solution. If we delete it the program works fine and even if you do not delete it gets deleted after sometime by itself. but will be created again after some time.

Its hard to post any code because there is no code that is giving error. But when I press (ctrl+F5) to open my project its giving error. Still for reference I created a webform Review.aspx based on a masterpage. I created a combobox and a gridview inside it. Here Combobox has some collection of numbers (GenreId) and when you select a GenreId it do Autopostback and Gridview shows the entry associated with the selected GenreId. [image]

And then I tried to debug it in a browser, its giving error (for some time).

Comment: Post the smallest code sample that repeats the problem. Otherwise we're just guessing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the reason. have you try after closing all the design windows?

> SQL Server 2005 express edition does not support multiple processes.
>   Only single process can access database at a time. So when a database
>   is accessed through visual studio, ASP.net runtime cannot access the
>   database. This will result into the internal server error. To prevent
>   this, VS 2005 places app_offline.htm file in the application's root
>   directory. The file contain above message. This causes ASP.net to put
>   the application in offline mode. Please note the accessing database
>   means opening any component of the database (I.e. table, view, stored
>   procedure etc.) into the design window. When design window is closed,
>   VS 2005 removes app_offline.htm file making the application in onliner
>   mode again.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/app_offline.aspx

Comment: Where did you find this source from? It looks like a very nice article to read?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the ASP.Net DLLs aren't properly flushed from the cache, which can cause issues between builds. I would close visual studio (and make sure the web server the app is running on is stopped) and then delete any ASP.Net temporary files that are typically located in the C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Version Number] for your application to help resolve the issue.

Comment: but why do Visual Studio create it? And if once deleted why do it create again?

Comment: I'm not sure why VS is creating it, that might be a setting for the project somewhere, but if it was created at one point in time, then the ASP.Net caching issues could be the reason why it keeps resurfacing.

Answer (score 0):

the app_offline.htm filename was introduced in ASP.NET 2.0 to make it much easier to show to visitors that the site's currently offline so that administrators could more easily upgrade the system or place a new version into production of the site. After removing that particular file the upgraded site's back available for people to see.

For more information take a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/App_5F00_Offline.htm-and-working-around-the-_2200_IE-Friendly-Errors_2200_-feature.aspx.

there is a file app_offline.htm on the root of your project.Remove it and build if you don't wanna see again

Comment: but why do Visual Studio create it? And if once deleted why do it create again?

Comment: check your IIS root for any app_offline.htm.If there any then remove it.See it works ? Yu can also take a look at http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Restart-Stop-Application.aspx

Comment: I already wrote this in my edited post. I know where the file is (can be deleted even from the solution), but why VS creating and deleting it on its own

Comment: Well i can let you know that devenv.exe is the only process that has anything to do with app_offline.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you can not find the App_offline.htm file,

Go to the App_Data folder and there you will find the app_offline.htm file.

Right-click on the file and select Delete.

Good luck!